# Issue with blocking site by hosts

Tags: windows-7

I have problem with blocking sites by hosts.ini .

For example I have defined:

```
www.todoist.com www.guardian.co.uk
```

and when I enter in webrowser (FF, Chrome, IE) www.guardian.co.uk it's redirecting me to www.todoist.com

But when I give address www.guardian.co.uk/sport it's redirecting me to www.todoist.com/sport .
Do You know how to manage with this problem  ?

Answer (score 1):

Hosts.ini? Did you mean "hosts" from C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc?

The correct format is

```
127.0.0.1 www.todoist.com www.guardian.co.uk
```

Or you can replace 127.0.0.1 with any invalid IP address.
Remember that if you need to prevent other users on your computer to visit those sites, if they have Administrator privileges, they can bypass your setting.

If you need more help, I'm here :)

Comment: Hosts.ini? Did you mean "hosts" from C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc - Yes